# How to create a new label in gmail using gmail query for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, gmail-api

I am Working on a gmail app.

I want to create a new label and I am using following code for that.

```
GTLQueryGmail *query = [GTLQueryGmail queryForUsersLabelsCreate];
query.addLabelIds = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"[Mailbox]", nil];
[self.service executeQuery:query
                  delegate:self
         didFinishSelector:@selector(displayResult:finishedWithObject:error:)];
```

But I am Getting error as following:-

```
Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=400 "(Invalid request)" UserInfo={error=Invalid request, NSLocalizedFailureReason=(Invalid request), GTLStructuredError=GTLErrorObject 0x7f8daae55980: {message:"Invalid request" data:[1] code:400}}
```

I am unable to understand the problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the Solution have to alloc a new label and add to the query as

```
GTLQueryGmail *query = [GTLQueryGmail queryForUsersLabelsCreate];
GTLGmailLabel *newLabel = [[GTLGmailLabel alloc] init];
newLabel.name = label;
query.label = newLabel;

[self.service executeQuery:query
                  delegate:self
         didFinishSelector:@selector(displayResult:finishedWithObject:error:)];
```